# Bash: If statement does not see the filename grab by loop

Tags: bash, command

I am trying to learn bash and I did a one liner like such:

```
for f in *; do echo $f; done
```

This prints the all the file name in current directory.

Output:

```
a file
testfile
```

Since f is able to grab "a file" just fine, then I would do something like this:

```
for f in *; do
    if [ -f ${f} ]; then
       LINE=$(wc -l < $f)
       WORD=$(wc -c < $f)
       echo $f ${LINE} ${WORD}
    fi
done
```

This script failed at line 4 because "a file" has space in them.

**What I need help with: Why does it fail?**

F is able to grab the filename properley. Intuitively, i would believe that `-f ${f}` would be able to check if `"a file"` is a file.

Why does that "a file" passed the for loop but failed at the if statement check?

Comment: You need to quote `$f` every where in each command.

Comment: Expanding the commandline is not done recursive, but only once. When `*` is expanded in filenames, these names are not split again on spaces. When you use `$f` in the loop the commandline is expanded again. Use quotes in the loop.

Comment: Shell syntax has a lot of sharp edges like this; I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for pointing out common problems/mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to (double) quote each reference of `$f` so that bash knows the 'a' and 'file' are not separate objects, eg:

```
for f in *; do
    if [ -f "${f}" ]; then
       LINE=$(wc -l < "${f}")
       WORD=$(wc -c < "${f}")
       echo "${f}" ${LINE} ${WORD}
    fi
done
```

Comment: You should also double-quote the argument(s) to the final `echo` command.

Comment: thanks, answer updated